# Editor broken when copying/pasting?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, editor

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404247/cant-find-windows-forms-application-for-c/32404584#32404584) recently copying the answer from another site cplusplus.com, the link is in the answer). My issue is that code does not format properly. I selected all the code and hit the `{}` button and even indented by hand, but is is not working? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not formatting correctly because it's inside a numbered list, inside a bulleted list. Each additional level of nesting requires another 4 spaces of indentation to get formatted as code. So in this case, you need 12 leading spaces.

Comment: Or put an empty comment string `<!-- -->` before the code block.